# translate mips pseudo instruction into machine code

Tags: mips, pseudocode, machine-code

I know how to translate regular MIPS code into machine language, but how to transfer pseudo instructions into machine code? For example pseudo branch instruction ble(branch on less equal). I can not find the opcode for ble on the mips reference sheet. How can I translate it?
I tried to resolve ble into two regular instructions,
ble $t0, $t1, L >> sub $t0, $t0, $t1
                   blez $t0, L
And then translate the two instructions into machine code. Is it seems to be right? Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a few minutes Googling trying to find some document that listed all the pseudo-instructions in MIPS assembly and their translations, but was unable to come up with success.

Instead, [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Pseudoinstructions) seems to have enough information to get the idea across.

To address your specific example of the `ble $rt, $rs, LABEL` pseudo-instruction, I believe that the correct translation into proper instructions is:

```
slt $at, $rs, $rt
beq $at, $zero, LABEL
```

Where of course `$at` is the register reserved for the assembler - for instances like this.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now. There are many ways to translate ble right? As long as the function of the translation is the same as ble?

Comment: There may be more than one way to do it, but of course you are looking for the fastest possible. Good to hear I helped you out, if it worked for you please accept answer :)